# Pacman method for move Java libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I'am working on Pacman clone with Java and libGDX
How to make Pacman move by pressing one button?

Here is my code for moving, but I think it's not the best option:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;


public class Hero {

    private int rightBorder;
    private int leftBorder;
    private int top;
    private int bottom;

    private GameController gc;
    private float cellX;
    private float cellY;
    private TextureRegion texture;
    private float speed;

    private boolean isPressedD;
    private boolean isPressedA;
    private boolean isPressedW;
    private boolean isPressedS;

    private float offset;

    private StringBuilder stringBuilder;
    private int score;






    public Hero(TextureAtlas atlas, GameController gc){
        this.texture = atlas.findRegion("Pacman");
        this.cellX = 1;
        this.cellY = 1;
        this.speed = 5f;
        this.isPressedD = false;
        this.isPressedA = false;
        this.isPressedS = false;
        this.isPressedW = false;
        this.offset = 36;
        this.stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        this.score = 0;
        this.gc = gc;
        this.leftBorder = 0;
        this.rightBorder = 15;
        this.top = 8;
        this.bottom = 0;
    }

    public void update(float dt){
        movement(dt);
        checkBounds();
    }

    private void checkBounds(){
        if (cellX > rightBorder){
            cellX = rightBorder;
        }
        if (cellX < leftBorder){
            cellX = leftBorder;
        }
        if (cellY > top){
            cellY = top;
        }
        if (cellY < bottom){
            cellY = bottom;
        }

//        if (position.x > 1280 - offset){
//            position.x = 1280 - offset;
//        }
//        if (position.x < 0 + offset){
//            position.x = 0 + offset;
//        }
//        if (position.y > 720 - offset){
//            position.y = 720 - offset;
//        }
//        if (position.y < 0 + offset){
//            position.y = 0 + offset;
//        }
    }

    public void movement(float dt){
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.D)){
            isPressedD = true;
            isPressedA = false;
            isPressedS = false;
            isPressedW = false;
        }
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.A)){
            isPressedD = false;
            isPressedA = true;
            isPressedS = false;
            isPressedW = false;
        }
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.S)){
            isPressedD = false;
            isPressedA = false;
            isPressedS = true;
            isPressedW = false;
        }
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.W)){
            isPressedD = false;
            isPressedA = false;
            isPressedS = false;
            isPressedW = true;
        }
        if (isPressedA){
            cellX -= speed * dt;
        }
        if (isPressedD){
            cellX += speed * dt;
        }
        if (isPressedS){
            cellY -= speed * dt;
        }
        if (isPressedW){
            cellY += speed * dt;
        }
    }

    public void renderGUI(SpriteBatch batch, BitmapFont font){
        stringBuilder.setLength(0);
        stringBuilder.append("Score: " + score);
        font.draw(batch, stringBuilder, 10, 700);
    }

    public void render(SpriteBatch batch){
        batch.draw(texture, cellX * GameMap.CELL_SIZE, cellY * GameMap.CELL_SIZE);
    }
}
```

Here is moving method directly:

```
public void movement(float dt){
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.D)){
        isPressedD = true;
        isPressedA = false;
        isPressedS = false;
        isPressedW = false;
    }
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.A)){
        isPressedD = false;
        isPressedA = true;
        isPressedS = false;
        isPressedW = false;
    }
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.S)){
        isPressedD = false;
        isPressedA = false;
        isPressedS = true;
        isPressedW = false;
    }
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.W)){
        isPressedD = false;
        isPressedA = false;
        isPressedS = false;
        isPressedW = true;
    }
    if (isPressedA){
        cellX -= speed * dt;
    }
    if (isPressedD){
        cellX += speed * dt;
    }
    if (isPressedS){
        cellY -= speed * dt;
    }
    if (isPressedW){
        cellY += speed * dt;
    }
}
```

It's working but I can't ckeck collisions with walls.

How to change method for moving?

I need to press button and release immediately.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

No need to create booleans and then do checks on them. Just check if the key is pressed and then put your code in that if statement.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;


public class Hero {

    private int rightBorder;
    private int leftBorder;
    private int top;
    private int bottom;

    private GameController gc;
    private float cellX;
    private float cellY;
    private TextureRegion texture;
    private float speed;

    private float offset;

    private StringBuilder stringBuilder;
    private int score;

   
    public Hero(TextureAtlas atlas, GameController gc){
        this.texture = atlas.findRegion("Pacman");
        this.cellX = 1;
        this.cellY = 1;
        this.speed = 5f;
        this.offset = 36;
        this.stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        this.score = 0;
        this.gc = gc;
        this.leftBorder = 0;
        this.rightBorder = 15;
        this.top = 8;
        this.bottom = 0;
    }

    public void update(float dt){
        movement(dt);
        checkBounds();
    }

    private void checkBounds(){
        if (cellX > rightBorder){
            cellX = rightBorder;
        }
        if (cellX < leftBorder){
            cellX = leftBorder;
        }
        if (cellY > top){
            cellY = top;
        }
        if (cellY < bottom){
            cellY = bottom;
        }

//        if (position.x > 1280 - offset){
//            position.x = 1280 - offset;
//        }
//        if (position.x < 0 + offset){
//            position.x = 0 + offset;
//        }
//        if (position.y > 720 - offset){
//            position.y = 720 - offset;
//        }
//        if (position.y < 0 + offset){
//            position.y = 0 + offset;
//        }
    }

    public void movement(float dt){
        if (Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Keys.D)){
            cellX += speed * dt;
        }
        else if (Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Keys.A)){
            cellX -= speed * dt;
        }
        else if (Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Keys.S)){
            cellY -= speed * dt;
        }
        else if (Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Keys.W)){
            cellY += speed * dt;
        }
    }

    public void renderGUI(SpriteBatch batch, BitmapFont font){
        stringBuilder.setLength(0);
        stringBuilder.append("Score: " + score);
        font.draw(batch, stringBuilder, 10, 700);
    }

    public void render(SpriteBatch batch){
        batch.draw(texture, cellX * GameMap.CELL_SIZE, cellY * GameMap.CELL_SIZE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working this way. I need to press button and immediately release. And then character move's continuously. That's why I create booleans variables.

Comment: Oh I see. You want to use isButtonPressed, not isButtonJustPressed. https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html
I updated my answer. That should work.